# PySpark RDD to dataframe with list of tuple and dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I have processed some data in pyspark and it is an RDD that has this structure

```
[(u'991', {'location': 'Australia', 'Age': '27', 'Colour': Pink}), (u'993', {'location': 'Singapore', 'Age': '55', 'Colour': Black}), (u'993', {'location': 'Mexico', 'Age': '12', 'Colour': Blue}), (u'994', {'location': 'USA', 'Age': '24', 'Colour': Red})]
```

How do I convert this structure into a Dataframe? My end goal is that I can store a hive table, with 4 columns (ID (i.e. 991,), Location, Age, Colour)

The Row solution does not seem to work given that the dictionary is within a tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert each tuple to a *Row* object and then call `toDF` method; `Row(ID=t[0], **t[1])` pass the dictionary in the tuple as keyword arguments to each row, and use `ID = t[0]` to create a new key value pair with `ID` as the key:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
rdd.map(lambda t: Row(ID=t[0], **t[1])).toDF().show()
+---+------+---+---------+
|Age|Colour| ID| location|
+---+------+---+---------+
| 27|  Pink|991|Australia|
| 55| Black|993|Singapore|
| 12|  Blue|993|   Mexico|
| 24|   Red|994|      USA|
+---+------+---+---------+
```

Comment: This does not seem to work unless i just do it on one of the datapoints i.e. t[1] or t[0]

Comment: @shecode, try now that I edited the answer as the swapping was necessary for the code to work. :)